# How to get a filtered List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

This is the scenario. I have the next class:

```
class A
{ 
    string  attribute1; 
    string  attribute2;
    List<B> attribute3;
}

class B 
{
    string attribute1;
}
```

And my program runs a:

```
list<Class A>    myList
```

I want to get, filtering using linq, a specific list Class A

So, as far as I reach, I am getting a list or a list through:

```
myList.SelectMany(o => o.attribute3.Where(p => p.attribute1 == "test")).ToList()

myList.SelectMany(o => o.attribute3.Select(p => p.attribute1 == "test")).ToList()
```

Any clue? Thanks mates.

Comment: What result you want to get?

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr. Thanks for your response. I want to get a filtered list Class.

Comment: you want to get all A classes which any B of A has test value?

Comment: I want to get a plain list of all Class A, that has a value == "test" in its attribute 3 (that is a List Class B). @HesamFaridmehr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run:

```
myList.Where(o => o.attribute3.Any(p => p.attribute1 == "test")).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes sure, Done :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks again :)